# How to open a tab-delimited file in Weka

Tags: weka

When I try to open a tab-delimited file in Weka it says: "file format is not recognized". In the subsequent dialog box it shows `weka.core.converters.CSVLoader` and says "Reads a source that is in comma separated or tab separate format." When I click the OK button, it throws an error saying "wrong number of values. Read 11, expected 10 line 4." I verified the same file in Excel that the line had 10 fields.

Could someone advise a workaround?

The data file cannot be converted to CSV format because some of the fields contain a comma.

Comment: CSV _can_ handle commas, as per [the spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180). Try converting to CSV from Excel if you're wary of doing so yourself — it should handle itself just fine.

Answer (score 1):

When installing the unofficial Weka package [common-csv-weka-package](https://github.com/fracpete/common-csv-weka-package), you can load tab-delimited CSV files using the `CommonCSVLoader` loader. Simply change the loader's format from `DEFAULT` to `TDF` (`-F` command-line option).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. So far the best solution I found is using R to convert a tabular data file into arff. Google two keywords "import data to R" and "export R data to weka arff". My second choice is using JMP or SAS to open a csv or Excel workbook and then export as CSV.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: for Windows 10, install the R language package from this url:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rio/index.html

install RStudio from:
https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download

from the prompt in RStudio follow the Import, Export, and Convert Data Files instructions here:
https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2015-11-15/web/packages/rio/vignettes/rio.html

works a treat, converted my .tsv files to Weka arff format no problem. The only thing I haven't done is test the arff files in Weka yet (and compare with Python sklearn results), as I'm hoping there isn't a problem with commas embedded in the text message bodies. Scikit-Learn and TfidfVectorizer has no problems with embedded commas in a tsv file!